# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined karma jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-services, angular-test

I need to create a test of this get, but every time I try I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

My service function

```
getAPICard(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.GET_APICard}`);
```

}

My spec.ts

```
it('testing get api', (done:DoneFn) =>{
  const mockObj = [{id:'1',
   title:'title', 
   description:'description',
   image: 'imagem',
   amount: 10
  }];

  httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(mockObj)).and.callThrough();

 modalIndicationService.getAPICard().subscribe(
   dados => {
    expect(dados).toEqual(mockObj, 'mockObj');
    done()
   },
   done.fail
 )
  
  expect(httpClientSpy.get.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'one call');
  done();
```

})

Comment: If you compare what you are returning with `returnValue` versus what the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-http-services) returns, what key difference do you see?

Comment: Also show how you are setting up `modalIndicationService` in the test and how `getAPICard` is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't have both `.and.returnValue` and `.and.callThrough()`. Only one of the two makes sense because `returnValue` will always return a value and `callThrough` will call the actual function.

Try changing this line to:

```
httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(mockObj));
```

The rest looks good.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO, but when I do that and it turns green, does it mean that my test is complete?